# Why unique_lock call unlock, when he does not owning mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, locking

In this example, std::unique_lock call with flag std::defer_lock. On cppreference written: "defer_lock_t    do not acquire ownership of the mutex"
and : "(destructor) unlocks the associated mutex, if owned "

And now, the question!

Why in this example, std::unique_lock calls unlock in destructors?

```
void transfer(Box &from, Box &to, int num)
{
    // don't actually take the locks yet
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(from.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(to.m, std::defer_lock);

    // lock both unique_locks without deadlock
    std::lock(lock1, lock2);

    from.num_things -= num;
    to.num_things += num;

    // 'from.m' and 'to.m' mutexes unlocked in 'unique_lock' dtors
}
```

?????

Comment: std::lock it just function. And they return void

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::defer_lock` serves to say "I will obtain the lock somehow later on", which the call to `std::lock(lock1, lock2)` does. Because of this, the locks call unlock in destructor. To test this out, you could try giving the mutexes to `std::lock` directly: `std::lock(from.m, to.m);`. If you do this, the `unique_lock`s will not unlock the mutexes, as they don't own them.

There is also `std::adopt_lock`, which says "I already own the lock".

These two approaches are mostly equivalent, except that you cannot use `std::defer_lock` with `std::lock_guard`, as it does not have `lock` method.